# Path deseado en iTextsharp (remoto)

Tags: c#, pdf, itextsharp

Con este código consigo crear el documento y asignerle un path en los archivos temporales:

```
   string nombre = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".pdf";
```

Y creo el documento:

```
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25);
```

Creamos el stream para escribir el documento:

```
  PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(nombre, FileMode.Create));
```

Abrimos el Doc:

```
    doc.Open();
```

Hacemos cosas en el pdf.

Cerramos el doc:

```
    doc.Close();
```

Imprimimos el doc:

```
    Process prc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    prc.StartInfo.FileName = nombre;
    prc.Start();
```

Bien, mi pregunta es, ¿cómo podria hacer para que, si estando la aplicación en un servidor y se ejecuta via net, hacer que el path se asigne en una carpeta "Descargas" por ejemplo, y el pdf se imprima en el PC que está ejecutando la app.

Pregunta en sencilla:

¿Cómo asigno un path local estando la app en remoto?

Answer (score 0):

SI la aplicación esta en el servidor, el cliente "descarga" el programa y lo ejecuta "local". Por lo que las rutas serán locales, así que no te preocupes.

Sobre definir la carpeta, puedes usar Environment.SpecialFolder... por ejemplo para mis documentos:

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments
```

Comment: nono, el cliente utiliza la aplicacion del servidor, no la descarga, es decir, hay un boton en la aplicacion que hace que los datos se impriman. La aplicacion se ejecuta en el servidor, y el PDF ha de "imprimirse" en local